# Mapping from text to value in Google sheet equation

Tags: google-sheets, mapping, equation

I have a Google Spreadsheet with two sheets in it. In one of them I have a table representing a mapping from text to a number like this:

| Text | Factor |
| --- | --- |
| Yearly | 1.0 |
| Quarterly | 4.0 |
| Monthly | 12.0 |
| Weekly | 52.0 |
| Daily | 365.0 |

In the second sheet I have a large table that has values like this:
| Value | Billing |
| --- | ---- |
| 150.0 | Yearly |
| 99.0| Quarterly |
| 1.25 | Monthly |

Now I want to calculate a yearly value with a calculation like this:
`=150.0*YEARLY+99.0*QUARTERLY+1.25*Monthly`
by defining an equation in my Google sheet and specifying the range of the value and billing cells since it is a long table. Is this at all possible? I know that I can easily just add the mapped value instead in the table, but these values are only a simple example, and there will be more mapped values later that will change with time. Instead of changing those factors manually one by one in the table, this solution with a mapping in a separate sheet would allow me to easily adjust this in the calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of XLOOKUP to convert the text values to their correlative number, you can then use SUMPRODUCT to multiply both columns and sum the result:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D2:D,XLOOKUP(E2:E,A2:A,B2:B,))
```

[image]